# How to split doxygen @mainpage documentation across several files

Tags: doxygen

I would like to include in the @mainpage section multiple .txt files (or .md files, written in markdown).

However, I get for each of these text files a separate chapter.  How can this prevented?

Comment: do you have a litte code example?

Answer (score 1):

I am here looking for an answer to the same problem, and since no one appears to have solved it, I have looked for a solution myself.

I have found this ...

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html

> Source files that are used as input to doxygen can be parsed by
> doxygen's built-in C-preprocessor. By default doxygen does only
> partial preprocessing.

So to split a page, e.g. the main page over several files, it looks like a solution is to fully enable the C preprocesor on the markdown files, and to use

> #include file1.md
>
> #include file2.md

etc to include the various markdown files.

What we would like to do is use Doxygen 's

> \include file1.md
>
> \include file2.md

but unfortunately Doxygen has second guessed that the files we want to include are code files.
In the same way that Doxygen has a \htmlinclude to save you writing two lines

> \htmlonly
>
> \endhtmlonly

specifying that the content is HTML, the \include command is really a sort of \codeinclude to save you specifying that the included content is software.

I would personally prefer to type an extra two lines specifying the nature of my included files: code, HTML, markdown, or whatever, and have a generic include command. But they say never look a gift horse in the mouth, which basically means you cannot argue with free software!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

`@mainpage`
`This is your live and it isn't getting any better then this! This is your life and it's ending one minute at a time!`

`<a href="/mnt/home/USER/vis/Doxyfile">Doxyfile</a> @n`

`<a href="/mnt/home/USER/vis/DoxygenLayout.xml">DoxygenLayout.xml</a><br>`

Put a `@n, \n, <br>` after each refrence, to break lines, otherwise everything will be put in one line.

---

You can also define a group, add the other refrences to that group: 

`@mainpage`

`@ref test`

First, you put the `@ref` tag to your mainpage. Then you define a group e.g.

`@defgroup   test`

`@{`

`<a href="/mnt/home/USER/vis/Doxyfile">Doxyfile</a>` 

`@}`

Now you start adding links, from other files, to that group with:

`@addtogroup`

`<a href="/mnt/home/USER/GROUP/Doxyfile">AnotherDoxyfile</a>`

However this will show only the groups name in your mainpage, not all files.

---

I assume what you want is, to put an anchor in a file:

`@anchor ANCHORTEST`

`@{`

`<a href="/mnt/home/stud-dral1012/vis/Doxyfile">TESTFILE</a>`

`@}`

And then later put that anchor in your mainpage:

`@mainpage`

`@ref ANCHORTEST @n`